# Libnl compatibility with kernel version

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

1. Is there any dependency between libnl and kernel version? I am using kernel version 4.1. What is the stable and suitable version of recommended libnl version for this kernel?
2. Is the latest libnl version(3.4.0) compatible with older kernel verions 3.x or do we need to select 3.2.25 for this?
3. I am facing an issue that, older libnl version in latest kernel gives kernel panic when I program more than 10000 routes in kernel, whereas iproute2 is working fine. So, I want to confirm if there is any libnl and kernel version dependency here.